# What algorithm is used by Disk Utility encryption?

Tags: encryption, ext4

What encryption algorithm is used by the partition encryption function of Disk Utility?

Comment: Ext4 does not have any encryption capability. If you have an encrypted ext4 filesystem, something else is doing the encryption, and if you don't tell us what it is, we can't tell.

Comment: @Gilles Thanks for pointing that out. Corrected the question.

Answer (score 1):

`gnome-disk-utility` uses `crypttab`, which in turn uses `luks` (linux unified key setup) and `dm-crypt` to provide encryption.

[Luks](http://code.google.com/p/cryptsetup/) uses [TKS1](http://code.google.com/p/cryptsetup/wiki/TKS1) and the PBKDF2 hash algorithm.